# Move values of different variables in the same observation

Tags: stata

I have a dataset imported from Excel where countries are stored as one variable, while their corresponding population are placed in a separate variable but in the next observation.

For example:

```
clear

input str32 country population
"United States of America" .
"" 3447
"Afghanistan"  . 
"" 727
"Belgium"  . 
"" 992
"China"  . 
"" 12000
end
```

How can I get the `population` values in the same observation as those in `country`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
replace population = population[_n+1] if population == .
drop if country == ""
```